# Why: Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type.. ReactNode

Tags: reactjs

I have following code:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ReactElement, ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { setAuthnRes } from '../slices/User'
import { store } from '../store'
import '../styles/globals.scss'
import { baseURL } from '../utils/baseURL'

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
    getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
    Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT ?? 'local',
    true
)

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
    const dispatch = store.dispatch
    const authnUserResp = store.getState().authnUser?.resp


    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>)

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider> // <------ HERE
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

And I get this:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ProviderProps<AnyAction> | Readonly<ProviderProps<AnyAction>>): Provider<AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/@types/styled-jsx/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ProviderProps<AnyAction>, context: any): Provider<AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/@types/styled-jsx/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.ts(2769)
```

in this line:

```
<Provider store={store}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider>
```

I did a `yarn cache clean`

Comment: From error msg: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. Could it be the optional tag in type NextPageWithLayout: `getLayout?` that causes the error?

Comment: affirmative, it helped, butthen I got an other for `Component` keyword with the same `'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.`

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to do with my limited knowledge, since I have never used redux before. If you are trying to set up layout for child component, you can just create a optional wrapper and dont have to pass it through provider

Comment: I upgraded to Next.js `12.1.0` and cleaned all node_modules, and problem disappeared

Answer (score 2):

*Just for highlighting solution, as [@János](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239219/j%C3%A1nos) advised higher in question comments:*

Just remove `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` file. And after **reinstall** deps.